# Android String Initialisation

Tags: java, android, arrays, string

I have a query about strings.

I'm declaring my string array as:

```
private static String[] name;
```

I'm then trying to add a string to it:

```
name[0] = temp    // Where temp as another string
```

I am getting a nullpointer error with the above code.  Am I initialising my string array correctly?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like you've missed to write
`name = new String[CAPACITY];`
somewhere

Answer (score 2):

If you want to add dynamically elements to an Array of Strings I would recommend you to do

```
private static ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<String>();
```

and then use below to add Strings:

```
name.add(temp);
```

If you know the size that it will have, then you can create an array like this:

```
private static String[] name = new String[10]; //if it's going to have 10 elements (typo corrected)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you have not initialized your string array.

You can declare and initialize it this way:

`private static String[] name = new String[4];` Where '4' is the size of your array.

or:

`private static String[] name = {temp, temp2, temp3};` Where the temps are each individual item in the array.

Answer (score 0):

At the point

```
private static String[] name;
```

in your code, 'name' is still `null`.

for an array of Strings you have to declare the (constant) number of strings you want to store.

```
int n = 10;
private static String[] name = new String[n];
```

You then cannot ever write more than `n` strings to your array.

If you want to have the number of strings dynamically, you have to use a `Vector<String>` or an `ArrayList<String>`. Both objects use the `myStrings.add(String string)`-method to add a string and you can access strings by calling `myStrings.get(int position)`.